# Omniauth login withouot requesting anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I am looking to use omniauth for user login. For security purposes I would like to request no data be requested from the provider.

I have tried:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'],  scope: '', info_fields: ''
end
```

However when I login to facebook I am still advised that my app will receive the user's public profile. When I click "Review the info you provide" I am unable to deselect the public profile information that includes name etc.

Is it possible to receive no identifying details?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible.

`user_profile` is the most basic permission, and gets asked for automatically during login, even if you don’t specify it.

> Is it possible to receive no identifying details?

Well you don’t actually want *none at all*, because without *something* to identify a user by, you would not have an actual login.

If your users might be concerned about your app invading their privacy, then I can only recommend that you explain to them in detail what data your app will get access to; and maybe also what parts of that data it will actually use. (If you only need the app-scoped user id for the purpose of identifying them in your login system, but not anything else - then you *could* only ask for their id. Users would have to trust you on that of course.)